# How to hide module name from url yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

I am new to yii2.

mydomain.com/organisation/banks/index

from above url i want to remove organisation.

i add following code to my config file under component section.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'modules/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ],
]
```

But still its not working.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the above URL the only one where you need to hide module name? Or are there multiple URLs to hide?

Comment: there are multiple URLs to hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of multiple URLs to hide I'm afraid you have to add the rule for each URL like:

```
'banks/index' => 'organisation/banks/index',
'something/another' => 'organisation/something/another',
```

If there is an unique controller's name that this module uses you can make it easier by adding general rule. For example if controller's name is `banks` and **there is no** `BanksController` under the top namespace level of app you can add:

```
'banks/<action>' => 'organisation/banks/<action>',
```

If `organisation` module is the only one your app uses and you don't need top namespace level controllers you can add:

```
'' => 'organisation',
```

So entering the domain URL address gets you directly to `organisation` module default route.

Comment: thanks.it solve my problem.
but i have more than 5 modules and each modules have more than 10 process(controller)
is there any easier way to make it general for all modules?

Comment: Why do you need to hide all the modules' names?

Comment: its my clinet's requirement

Comment: So either you add all the rules one by one or find some way to make general rules for similar groups of URL or create top namespace level controllers that will map module controllers. In every case it's tedious job.